# PHP DOMNode value

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I'm currently struggling with a really weird problem. Ive got an XML which looks like this:

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <D>
       <E attribute="foo">
         This is a value
       </E>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Now when I'm executing my XPath-Query and traverse the result, I'm always getting the value "This is a value" as value of node A, which is not correct (The value should only be node E's value).

What is going wrong here? Seems like when saying A->childNodes, it gets all childNodes recursively and overwrites the values.

Any help would greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: Are you echoing this to a browser, by any chance? Try viewing the source and you will see why you are seeing this behaviour... ;-)

Comment: How do you traverse through your XML? DOM? Your XPath-query please.

Answer (score 1):

The handler for $node->nodeValue is `dom_node_node_value_read` which is impementated in [ext/dom/node.c](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/dom/node.c?view=log).
It calls [libxml2's xmlNodeGetContent()](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeGetContent) function.

> Read the value of a node, this can be either the text carried directly by this node if it's a TEXT node **or the aggregate string of the values carried by this node child's** (TEXT and ENTITY_REF). Entity references are substituted.

I.e. for a DOMElement you get all the values of all the child elements as one string.
That's not what http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-1841493061 says if I'm not mistaken... but that's how it is implemented in libxml2/php

Comment: Interesting, I'd assumed the problem was that it was effectively calling `$node->C14N()` and returning entire the content tags included, and the browser was then eating the tags when rendering. But it sound like libxml does something, er, *unexpected* here. Looks like you'd have to check `$node instanceof DOMText` in order for this to be "safe".